# Getting object at location on screen in Metal

Tags: ios, graphics, 3d, uitapgesturerecognizer, metal

I'm using Metal and I want the user to be able to tap certain objects onscreen. I'm using a tap gesture recognizer, and so I have a CGPoint, but I don't know how to find the object at that point. Is there either a way to get the onscreen coordinates for metal, or a way to transform the CGPoint into the metal coordinate space?

Comment: What is "object" and what is "at a point"? These are not Metal concepts; what does "using Metal" mean in your context?

Comment: @Jessy An object is just a collection of triangles, and by "at a point", I mean that I am trying to determine what object the triangles that are displayed at that point on the screen belong to.

Comment: I think the main two reasons that Metal doesn't represent those concepts are that not every triangle is opaque, and that mesh colliders on every object wouldn't match up with primitive colliders that some of them will use for other purposes. I recommend that you go experiment with raycasts and colliders in Unity for a little while, and then revisit this question after being informed by that. It's very easy to be educated quickly by Unity.

Comment: @Jessy The reason I asked this question is that I am trying to do it specifically in Metal, and so I'm asking about techniques that work within Metal. Unity might be helpful for a general 3D math perspective, but I still need to know what I can access in Metal to do this.

Comment: Going to Unity will show you what all name-brand engines implement, which is a physics engine. Raycasts are handled via their collider systems. That may or may not be what your specific needs require. It's not the math that's important, but the mental model of what "objects" are. You're not on the GPU's wavelength at the moment. Learning about how little it knows about your mental model will help you either implement a translator, or find one that works for you. Also, Unity uses Metal, so that translator may indeed be Unity. That's why I asked you what "using" means to you.

Comment: @Jessy I certainly understand what all the terminology I used means and how it is represented on the GPU, and since I am trying to calculate whether the ray from the camera through that point on the screen will intersect with a certain bounding box, the math is absolutely important. My question regarded what kind of information I could get from Metal, which would help in coming up with an algorithm for the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this with a raytracing-type technique. I used a bounding sphere for each object and calculated whether or not the ray intersected it and how far from the ray's origin the intersection was, with the ray being from the camera through the onscreen point of clicking. The code is as follows:

```
    var location = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(self.view)
    var proj_matrix = projectionMatrix.copy()
    var view_matrix = worldMatrix.copy()
    var x = (2.0 * location.x) / self.view.bounds.size.width - 1.0;
    var y = 1.0 - (2.0 * location.y) / self.view.bounds.size.height;
    var newLocation = simpleVertex(x: Float(x), y: Float(y), z: Float(-1.0))
    var projSpaceLoc = GLKMatrix4MultiplyVector4(GLKMatrix4Invert(proj_matrix.matrix(), nil), GLKVector4Make(newLocation.x, newLocation.y, newLocation.z, 1.0))
    projSpaceLoc = GLKVector4Make(projSpaceLoc.x, projSpaceLoc.y, -1.0, 0.0)
    var viewSpaceLoc = GLKMatrix4MultiplyVector4(GLKMatrix4Invert(view_matrix.matrix(), nil), projSpaceLoc)
    GLKVector4Normalize(viewSpaceLoc)
    //tappable is an array of nodes that can be tapped
    for node in tappable {
        var r: Float = node.r //this is the radius of the bounding sphere for that node
        var c: GLKVector4 = node.origin //this is the origin of the bounding sphere
        var little_c = GLKVector4DotProduct(c, c) - powf(r, 2)
        var b = GLKVector4DotProduct(viewSpaceLoc, c)
        var discriminant = powf(b, 2) - little_c
        //If the discriminant is positive, their are two points of intersection, if it is 0, one point, and if it is negative, no points.
     if (discriminant >= 0) {
            var t_1 = (Float(-1.0)*b) + sqrtf(discriminant)
            var t_2 = (Float(-1.0)*b) - sqrtf(discriminant)
            if (intersect != nil) {
                if (min(t_1, t_2) < intersect.intersect_point) {
                    intersect = (node, min(t_1, t_2))
                }
            } else {
                intersect = (node, min(t_1, t_2))
            }
        }
    }
```